# Controlling for strongly collinear variables in a multivariate model

Tags: r, mixed-model, multivariate-analysis, multicollinearity, ecology

I am looking for some advice for a research project I am working on. My project involves analysis of fish abundance data from rivers around NSW Australia, with an aim of assessing the impacts of dams on fish communities. I have thousands of observations in my dataset from a number of rivers, and each has electrofishing catch data for around 30 fish taxa. Each river has multiple dams, ranging from 4 to about 30. My hypothesis is that dams will disrupt natural longitudinal patterns in fish communities, creating discrete changes in community structure on either side. I am interested in determining both which dams have the greatest impacts, and assessing cumulative impacts of multiple dams along the course of a river.

One approach I am taking for this question is to assign each fish catch site a number of downstream dams (n_dams), and fitting a multivariate model with n_dams as a fixed factor (along with covariates such as season, time of day etc.). However, the number of dams downstream of a site is obviously directly correlated to how upstream the site is, something we already know is a strong predictor of fish communities. This means that really all I am doing is modelling how fish communities change along a river.

To control for this I am considering including distance upstream as a random effect in my model, so the impacts of dams can be isolated. However, I am worried this will chew up a lot of the variance which is explained by dams, given how strongly correlated they are. Another option would be to construct two models, a null model with just distance and an alternate with both distance and number of barriers, and then look for a statistical difference between model. Again, I'm not sure if this actually solves my issue. Also, I'm not sure either of these approaches will make it easy for me to isolate the impacts of different dams.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated, I've been stumped on this problem a while. At the moment I have been working predominantly with the mvabund, gllvm, brms, and Hmsc packages in R, so any info on implenting what I want to do with these packages would be extra helpful. I am comfortable with any frequentist, Bayesian, or machine learning approaches to my problem.

Cheers!

Comment: Do you know what the extent of the correlation actually is between distance upstream and number of dams?

Comment: @GeorgeSavva This differs between rivers. The lowest is the Gwydir with a Pearson correlation of 0.84, highest is the Lachlan with a correlation of 0.97. Most are ~0.9

Comment: Sorry I meant in the dataset not each river individually.  An extremely high correlation within each river is guaranteed.

Comment: @GeorgeSavva In the dataset it is 0.75. However, I feel this might be misleading, since distances are not equivalent between rivers. I.e, distance 50km in the Namoi might have 10 dams, while Murrumbidgee only has 2 at the same distance. I believe if I added distance as a random effect, I would need river as a random slope to account for this.